# How can I regain access to the network if my IP address is banned due to be a part of a botnet?

Tags: support, ip-ban

[image: Access Denied]

when I sent an email to the team, they replied:

> We're sorry that you got caught up in this. Your IP address is being blocked by our system because it is likely that your computer is participating in a **botnet**.
>
> We hope you understand that we take actions like this only when absolutely necessary, and find an alternate way to access the site.

How can I regain access to the network?

Comment: Well, you posted this so you found a way. Congrats! :)

Comment: I use friend office network, which is different IP address. =.='''

Comment: [Blurring and pixelation are not secure ways to hide data](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129683/is-image-blurring-an-unsafe-method-to-obfuscate-information-in-images).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your computer (or a home appliance that is connected to the internet, like a webcam, your refrigerator, etc.) is most likely used for an attack on the Stack Exchange (or your IP address falls in a range that was blocked for that reason). It is possible you have some programs running on your machine that gives others control over your computer.

What you need to do is remove that software. This might be a hard job since often those programs are very good in disguising themselves. Usually I advice people to reinstall their machine. Only use legitimate software obtained directly from the source. A virus scanner may be of help, but not always.

Comment: Might also be accessory like webcam which has been compromised...

Comment: Indeed. Or a refrigerator nowadays :) In fact anything that connects to the internet @Sha

Comment: Thanks, mean that I have no other way, I have to one by one checking my office staff PC or other that is connected to the internet. But how I am going to check I am still participating in a botnet?

Comment: Monitor your internet traffic. Although it is very hard to diagnose these things (that is why they get that big).

Comment: @chchin Actually, even if you remove the malware/virus, you still won't be able to access for a while, until the automated system will realize the IP is no longer used to attack them. So all in all, I'm afraid you'll just have to wait it out, or use a different IP. (there are ways to change IP.)

Comment: Yes, or one of the network guys enables your access again and monitors if anything happens. That is why you need to contact them.

Comment: This can occur if you are on a VPN and you are routing all of your internet traffic though the VPN and said VPN's hosted IP is blacklisted.